# RTSP multistreaming from Deepstreaming Doesnt load on FFMPEG

Tags: nvidia-deepstream

Hi I am working on a project wherein the streams are passed to Deepstream and encoded out as h264 codec,streams are fetched by VLC and gstreamer but not by ffmpeg, For refernce this is link to the sample code https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/deepstream_python_apps/blob/master/apps/deepstream-rtsp-in-rtsp-out/deepstream_test1_rtsp_in_rtsp_out.py

i also tried with rtspclientsink instead of rtsp server from gstreamer, still no luck